# Get Google Blockly Block by Id?

Tags: blockly

I would like to query the DOM to get a block by ID. Currently I have to find all elements by class name, and manually extract the correct index, which is not sustainable.

How can give a block a unique ID?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All blocks already have an id ([api docs](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Block#id)). However, a Block object isn't a DOM object so you won't find it by using `document.getElementById(..)`. Instead you'll use [`Workspace.getBlockById(..)`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Workspace#.getBlockById). Your workspace is usually [`Blockly.mainWorkspace`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly#.mainWorkspace)

Comment: Thanks for that! I can console.log(Blockly.mainWorkspace); but there isn't any getById option?

Comment: Whoops. It looks like `Workspace.getById(..)` is a static method for looking up Workspace objects. The method I meant is `.getBlockById(..)`. Corrected above.